# Blog Volunteers - Unite

Tags: discussion, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Contributing to the Blog](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog)

The blog [is moving forward](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/lets-get-the-blog-kicked-off/2979#2979). **The wheels are moving** higher up to get us a Wordpress instance created for a dedicated blog here are Programmers.StackExchange. I'm excited about the prospects and what this can do for our community at large.

A couple of things to note.

1. There is now a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2359/programmers-blog) for discussions regarding the P.SE blog. There has already been a healthy discussion and if you're interested I would suggest that you peruse the transcripts.
2. I have [been anointed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3214146#3214146) the community "point of contact" for the blog. All this means is that I'll be putting in some dedicated hours to organizing and communicating with people about getting the blog published.

Some time ago, I posted [a call for volunteers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/who-would-contribute-to-a-p-se-blog) for the blog - and we received a great response from potential writers and proofreaders. However, it has been some time since those "commitments" were made and situations may have changed. If you're still interested - or have become interested - please refer to that [original post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/who-would-contribute-to-a-p-se-blog) and post a comment to the affirmative if you are still willing to participate.

**Here's where we're at**.

It was recommended that we find time for everyone who is interested to sit down and have a discussion about the direction of the blog. We've already had several discussions about this here on Meta but I agree that it probably is a good idea to schedule a chat room session where we can have a meeting and intimately discuss the details of this new project - i.e. definite plans for articles (aka blog posts), proofreading, and publication.

I propose that we hold this meeting **[Friday, February 3rd at 4 PM GMT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2359/programmers-blog?tab=schedule)** (that's 11 AM for United States East Coast) in the new Programmers Blog chat room.

If you are intending to be a participant in this project, please give me feedback on whether this date and time works for you.

Comment: Would be available 14:00:00 GMT - 15:30:00 GMT, 9 out of 10 times on Wed,Fri,Sat. Would support even if can't make it to the chat room.

Comment: Would there be other meeting times? That listed time is in the middle of the work day for me (and most other people on the east or central US and early or just before the work day out west), so I won't be able to actively participate in the chat. Depending on what is going on, I might have it open, but probably can't become actively involved in the discussion since I'll be working.

Comment: Regarding the chat: Let's keep it simple. Everyone can chime in at any time, and add to the discussion. I'd say we can start on Friday and have a definite deadline on Sunday, after which Jarrod can read through everything and decide what's important and what's not. That way everyone interested can contribute, regardless of timezones. It's not a Town Hall chat, let's keep it casual, it's mostly for us to get to know each other a bit better, as we already have a pretty extensive list of topics.

Comment: Would agree with Rizos. Plus, atleast a couple of programmers are going to be there at any time. So there won't be a big problem in following up. We can always ping in case of need. Any important decision would be post on meta.

Comment: @YannisRizos - Good points; discussion can happen throughout those days and people can leave messages if no one else is there to actively participate.

Comment: I won't be able to make it to the chat, but I'll check back after and see if there's anything I can contribute.

Comment: I will be there..

Comment: I'll be on campus with little to do.

Comment: Duping this to the latest status update, so people can get the latest info about the progress of the blog.