# Programmers Blog: Second Call for Contributors

Tags: discussion, blog

First of all, if you didn't know (and I can only hope you did), Programmers Stack Exchange has it's [own community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/) that anybody can contribute to. So, if you haven't been reading it, start now :-)!

Anyways, currently we have very few solid contributors to the blog. We started with about 7 posts, and that number is quickly falling. Basically, if we don't get more community help with this, we are going to be on the verge of dying. So if you want to contribute, now is the time to start.

Currently, we are in need of mainly writers, although if you would like to sign-up as an editor or proofreader, that would be fine.

To sign up, set up your answer as so:

> ## Name
>
> ***Position (either editor/proofreader or writer or both)***
>
> Description.

If you are a writer, your description area is where you should put how many posts you'll be able to dish out per month or another time span. For example, `1 post every 1-2 months`. If you only want to write one post, and then stop helping, that's also fine, although we would love to see you stay.

Once you sign up, we will contact you with your Wordpress account details and Trello account details. For more info on those services, and on how you will be helping, [see here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog). If you have any questions, ping me in the [Programmers Blog Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2359/programmers-blog), or leave a comment.

That's about it! Enjoy the blog, and start signing up :-)!

**Addendum**

> Register on Trello with the handle you use here. I'll invite you once
>   you ping me in the programmers blog chatroom. WP access can be gained
>   by listing your email either in that chat or in your post here. If you
>   want to be private about it send it to programmer.se.blog (at)
>   gmail.com with the subject line: Programmer Blog Sign-up. Please
>   indicate your handle in the message as well.

Comment: Note: This is not a duplicate as this is a _second_ call for contributors. Also, this post will be used to keep track of our members in the public eye. Thanks!

Comment: We really should make the Programmers blog more visible.  There's nothing on the main site to indicate that it even exists.

Comment: I agree with @Walter, it would make it much more attractive for contributors if it has more visibility among the community.

Comment: @Walter I completely agree, but I don't see a way to do that without adding something to the site design, which would add to Jin's heavy workload. If you want, create another Meta post on the topic of visibility.

Comment: @Dynamic - Great idea... Done. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3780

Comment: Is there an "official" document, describing the scope and topics that should be covered on the blog?

Comment: @K.Steff http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/about/

Comment: @Dynamic: I'm not quite sure... it seems we are able to put in this blog anything

Comment: @HoàngLong I don't see why you would think that...

Comment: @Dynamic: maybe I just not get it yet, but we will cover from algorithm, technology,... to community actions as well. It seems too broad to me. Maybe I just not feel the "main idea" of this blog yet...

Comment: @HoàngLong I think the topic of the blog was anything that would be interesting or relevant to Programmers, providing it relates to their career choice (or self identity) as a programmer. So yes, that is a very broad scope :)

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for explaining that :-). I tried doing so in the chat room, but it was like 1 a.m. and I was half asleep :P

Comment: @Rachel: thanks, it's clearer now :)

Comment: @Dynamic: hi, I haven't got any contact yet. How's the plan going?

Comment: @HoàngLong We are in the middle of the process. Depending on how fast we can get what we need from SE it may take another week... Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @Dynamic: no problem. I just want to make sure that we are in touch :)

Comment: `We started with about 7 posts, and that number is quickly falling.`  uh-oh, are they getting deleted?   :)

Comment: @MattFenwick No they're getting published :-)

Comment: What are the advantages/benefits of posting on this blog as opposed to posting on one's own blog? I don't see any selling points here... ;)

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe brought up a good point. What are the advantages of posting here vs my own blog? Well... fix the visibility problem, first and foremost. Then one of the advantages/benefits can be "more visibility".

Comment: @jmort253 Definitely more visibility. But, of course, this entire blog is run by community volunteers, so there isn't much a material benefit. On the other hand, you're helping yourself by getting publicity, as we encourage that your name to be shown. Plus, some people think its fun (me) to get to collaborate with different people while working on this :-).

Answer (score 9):

### Justin Kohlhepp

**Writer, 1 post every 1-2 months**

I maintain my own blog at the moment at [RationalGeek.com](http://rationalgeek.com/blog).  The topics I write about are pretty well aligned to the subject matter of Programmers.SE.  I'd be glad to contribute some posts to P.SE blog as long as I can also post them on my site.  Not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed and probably even encouraged if you provide a link back to the P.SE blog. I'm the author of one of the current blog posts, and re-posted it on my own blog along with a little header line saying it was originally written for the P.SE blog, and included a link going there.

Comment: Yup. As @Rachel said, you have to provide a link-back, but it is allowed.

Comment: @Dynamic that is exactly what I want to do.  Providing a link-back would be fine.

Comment: @Dynamic A link back isn't required, its just requested. All our writers are volunteers, and if they spend time writing an article for us, they're welcome to do whatever else they want with it.

Comment: @Rachel I'm pretty sure blog posts are under the [same license as the site itself](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: @Rachel What Dynamic said, the "rules" are the same as with posts on the main site.

Comment: @jkohlhepp Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 8):

Julie Meloni (that's me)

writer, 1 post every 1-2 months; editor/proofreader as much as you want it

Comment: Glad to see you're interested. Welcome aboard.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: @jcmeloni Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 3):

## Matt Davey

***Writer, 1 post per month***

I maintain a blog at http://mattdavey.me/ I'd be happy to submit all my future posts to Programmers blog first and then clone them on my personal blog.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 3):

### James Kingsbery

***Writer, 1 post every 2 months***

I have a blog at [kingsbery.net](http://kingsbery.net). I've been meaning to be better about posting regularly, this will give me incentive to do so.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Comment: I signed into Trello, but don't see the P.SE blog board anywhere. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Ping me in the Blog Chat Room with your Trello name. I will invite you to the board. Also, I will invite you to Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

## Dan McGrath

***Proofreader, occasionally a writer***

To see an example of my writing when I put in some effort, skip to page 12 of this mag: [Spectrum Nov/Dec 2011](http://www.intl-spectrum.com/t/136837/link.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 3):

## Bryan Dunsmore

***Editor/Proofreader***

I have a good command of the English language and would love to contribute. The End.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 2):

## Muhammad Alkarouri

***Writer, 1 post per month***

I will take one question from P.SE or SO and expand on it, giving my own understanding and/or reviewing some literature about it.

Comment: PS: I am posting this for completeness. Have already contacted editors on chat.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Answer (score 1):

## Le Do Hoang Long

*Writer, 1 post every 1,2 months & proofreader*

I maintain a simple blog at https://ledohoanglong.wordpress.com. My English writing skill may be not very good, but I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Thanks for you interest in contributing to the blog! Sorry it took so long, but we are finally ready to give you access! Please read the addendum in the original question for more information, and I hope to see you on the team soon!

Comment: @Dynamic: excuse me, but where is the "original question"? The first call, the second call, or on the blog itself?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but I meant the question that this answer is attached to. The second call.