# Programmers Blog visibility

Tags: feature-request, blog

I've been following the Meta discussions that have been taking place for quite a while about the creation of our community blog.  And recently Dynamic posted here [asking for more contributors](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3777) to the blog.  I had no idea the blog was up and running and that there'd already been several good entries posted.

If I can't find the Blog, what chance does someone have of finding it who isn't familiar with the site or even know that discussions have taken place?

I think it would be a good idea to have our [community blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/) be made visible somewhere on the main site.  More visibility would drive more interest and probably make requests for more contributors a thing of the past.

Comment: the blog link on the header _should_ be pointing to our blog ibstead of the SE blog, and our blog posts are shown in the community bulletin when posted. On mobile now can't verify everything works as expected...

Comment: @YannisRizos I have no [blog] link at the top of the main page

Comment: @YannisRizos That puny link? It blends in with the page :P.

Comment: @rachel ah, it was moved to the footer recently. even more out of the way I guess

Comment: @YannisRizos Wow, I *never* look at the footer

Comment: @Rachel You should, lots of cool stuff in the footer ;) click "contact us" for example (it's new)

Comment: @YannisRizos Can we [feature] this?

Comment: I didn't even realize there was new stuff on the blog until I saw this meta post...

Answer (score 6):

Something us regular users can do would be to make an ad for the blog in the [Community Promotion Ads](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2635/1130) meta post, and vote it up a few times so it shows up on occasion in the advertisement box on the right side of the screen.

---

[Thanks to Morons](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2012/3905#3905), we now have an ad for the blog.

> [image: Screenshot of ad]

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: You brought this up before in chat if I recall correctly. I thought it was a good idea, but I never actually got around to doing anything (sorry about that ;-). @YannisRizos Are we allowed to create new ads now, or do we have to wait until we start doing the 2013 ads?

Comment: @YannisRizos HA! ME! AND PHOTOSHOP! That's like giving a knife to a blind, elderly man who points a lot!

Comment: @Dynamic Yes, I did bring it up in chat before however I figured it would get more visibility in a meta post and would be more likely to get done :)

Comment: I made a Basic Ad... (My Creative Skill are very Limited) http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2012/3905#3905

Comment: @Morons Looks good!

Comment: @Morons very nice ad.

Answer (score 4):

As a start, we've increased the duration new blog posts appear in the sidebar's Community Bulletin from 3 to 7 days.

This number is open to experimentation, but we would like to avoid keeping items in the Bulletin for too long.

Comment: Can we put a link to the blog in the header or footer? I was looking to read the blog, but nothing has been posted in the last 7 days, so I had to dig through chat and meta to find a link. Surely there's a more accessible way to promote the blog?  How about replacing "Winter Bash" next to the global inbox with "Programmers Blog" one Winter Bash is over?

Comment: @jmort253 there is a link to the community blog in the footer on the main site.

Comment: Is this a feature that can be altered by moderators of the community, or is this a network wide, dev only feature?

Answer (score 3):

How about a split feed from the Community Bulletin on the upper right of the page?  So it would be a line or two from the blog and a line or two from Meta.  MetaP.SE is fairly low-volume anyway, so devoting some of the real-estate to the blog seems like a good use.

Comment: We have a feed from the blog in the Community Bulletin already. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If the blog already has a feed in the community bulletin, then I guess my comment isn't as relevant.  I don't recall having seen a link to any topics from there, just meta postings / links.

Answer (score -4):

I think creating a meta post linking to a new article with each posing would be acceptable.

Also there should be a line the FAQ about the blog, maybe under the what if I need more help section.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the meta site for discussions on the main site, and not use it for advertisement :)