# Programmers Blog: Call Round Three...Write!

Tags: discussion, blog

As some of you may have noticed, the Programmers Blog hasn't had a new post in a month. Part of this is due to issues with my school causing distractions. While I am well and capable of managing the blog, I can't populate articles all by my lonesome. Morons and others have done a terrific job in the past writing useful and interesting articles.

I'd like to hear even more voices. So, if you want to write for the blog and don't have access to the Trello board and the Wordpress instance, let me know by posting below and I'll set you up. You'll also need to send an email to programmer.se.blog (at) gmail.com with subject line : Blog Access. Also register on Trello and list your handle and I'll add there too. General Information and what nots can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog).

You can write on just about anything you care to within the site's scope. Some things that are off topic or not-constructive make perfect blog topics.

Comment: My apologies - I got access to the blog and it kinda slipped my mind with lots of other stuff happening. I will revisit for you :)

Comment: I don't have access to wordpress or trello. Could I get a link or some such?

Comment: @earlz email the address in the post and then register with your handle you use here on Trello

Comment: Also, linking to this question might help: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/contributing-to-the-blog

Answer (score 3):

I'd be interested in writing a blog entry about what we skills we need to develop as professional programmers. The technical side is just 50%. The article would be based on this answer - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185236/44081 that Yannis suggested could make a good article.

Comment: programmer.se.blog (at) gmail.com with subject line : Blog Access. Also register on Trello and list your handle and I'll add there too.

Answer (score 3):

It probably seems like I dropped off the face of the earth there, but I had a *small* change in employment. There was a bit of perfect storm which effectively nixed my being able to contribute to.... anything.

1. Got married.
2. Wife got pregnant almost immediately afterward.
3. Moved across the country to California to take a job with Apple.
4. Apple has something of a "just don't" policy to public speaking unless you're cleared by PR.

Thankfully though, I was told that I can do public speaking (in this case, blogging) so long as I don't actually talk about anything* specific with the company. I have time to contribute, so I'm back and I can start writing.

**Anything meaning anything and everything to do with the company from here on out until the end of time.*

Comment: You're still enabled as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

I do share opinions about [software development](http://blog.8thcolor.com/2013/02/about-being-a-team-leader/) on a [regular](http://blog.8thcolor.com/2012/09/modularization-in-rails-a-case-study/) basis using my own blog. Are you looking only for original/exclusive content, or is cross post (in one direction or another) something that would be possible ?

I'm not talking about recyclying, more about posting the same (new) content both here and on my personal/company blog.

Comment: Simultaneous Releases are fine as far as I'm concerned so long as the blog is yours.

Comment: The big thing is that any content on SE including the blogs is subject to the content license for the site. As long as you're cool with that, things should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be quite interested in getting involved in the programmers blog.

I write essays fairly frequently, but post them fairly infrequently on my [personal site](http://www.ed-j.co.uk/Blog) about a relatively broad range of topics (from performance development to code examples and coding techniques). I'd be happy to brush off some of the non-posted works (or brush up some of the posted ones to be more appropriate) if the sorts of topics I write about (development practices, methodologies, and tooling) are considered appropriate enough, and interesting enough, for the programmers blog!

Comment: Sign up for Trello and email the address listed in the main post so I can add you on Trello and on Wordpress.

Comment: @WorldEngineer I sent the email but have yet to have a reply. If it helps, my Trello handle is edwardwoodcock

Answer (score 1):

For the past couple years, I've been slowly building a document I call "Software Engineering Wisdom".  It's a collection of important things I've learned in my 9 years so far as a software engineer, some of which I really wished someone had told me early in my career.

It mostly focuses on the non-technical, sociological side of the software engineering which is often under-valued and under-developed.  I've discovered that I’m much more interested in these aspects of the craft than the technological aspects because I've noticed that most software project failures are due to sociological issues, not technical issues - a point which is written about in high detail in the book "Peopleware".

I've used some of this information in a presentation to CS students at my local university, but other than that, I have no solid plans on what to do with this repository of knowledge and lessons learned.  I think this blog would be a perfect way to get this information out there so others can benefit from it.  I could either write in depth about one piece of wisdom or just touch on many pieces.

Comment: My Trello handle is @cfl_jeff